# How to return an object which has difference between two array object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

for example

```
let array1 = [
  { 'id': 1010, 'name': 'grapes' }, 
  { 'id': 2020, 'name': 'blueberry' },
  { 'id': 3030, 'name': 'banana' }
]

let array2 = [
  { 'id': 1010, 'name': 'apple' }, 
  { 'id': 2020, 'name': 'blueberry' }, 
  { 'id': 4040, 'name': 'banana' },
  {'id' : 5050, name 'jackfruit'}
]
```

output should be

```
let result = [
  { 'id': 1010, 'name': 'grapes' },
  { 'id': 3030, 'name': 'banana' },
  { 'id': 4040, 'name': 'banana' },
  { 'id' : 5050, name 'jackfruit'}
]
```

here need to get an array which has uncommon object data
ENTRY 
`{ 'id': 2020, 'name': 'blueberry' }` is removed as id and name are commom in both array

Comment: `apple` and `grapes` have the same `id`. Is this deliberate?

Comment: Another way of asking that: why does your expected result not include `{ 'id': 1010, 'name': 'apple' }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples use the dataset from the original question but the logic still stands for the updated question.

Depending on the result you want, you can get the difference between the arrays like this:

```
const result = _.differenceWith(array1, array2, _.isEqual);
```

That will output

```
{ id: 1010, name: "grapes" }
```

If you want the symmetric difference you can concatenate the opposite as well:

```
const result = _.differenceWith(array1, array2, _.isEqual).concat(_.differenceWith(array2, array1, _.isEqual));
```

This will give you

```
{ id: 1010, name: "grapes" }
{ id: 1010, name: "apple" }
{ id: 3030, name: "banana" }
```

The result you have quoted in your question is slightly different, it is neither difference or symmetric difference, if you only want one result for each ID you would need to remove the second occurence of any object that has an ID key that already exists like so:

```
result = result.filter((elm, i) => !result.find((elm2, j) => elm.id === elm2.id && i > j) );
```

that will give you

```
{ id: 1010, name: "grapes" }
{ id: 3030, name: "banana" }
```

Comment: Your fiddle is blocked for me by some corporate firewall, but I get a different result with your symmetric difference call: https://runkit.com/crosseye/so60812738.  Result: `1010 grape, 3030 banana, 1010 apple, 4040 banana, 5050 jackfruit`.  This is what I would expect, and I don't know why the question is asking for something different.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That is because the question has been edited with a new dataset since I answered. However the result you are getting is the symmetric difference of the dataset you are inputting :)

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to roll your own.

The following code finds the union, sorts it by the relevant property, and then traverses it. If a key is the same as the previous, then a duplicate has been found and both elements are removed.

```js
function except(a,b) {
    const union = [...a, ...b]
    union.sort(({id: id1}, {id: id2}) => id1 - id2)
    const except = []
    let previous = null
    for(const el of union) {
        if(el.id === previous) {
            except.pop()
            continue;
        }
        except.push(el)
        previous = el.id
    }
    return except
}

let arr1 = [
  { 'id': 1010, 'name': 'grapes' }, 
  { 'id': 2020, 'name': 'blueberry' },
  { 'id': 3030, 'name': 'banana' }
]

let arr2 = [
  { 'id': 0000, 'name': 'apple' }, 
  { 'id': 2020, 'name': 'blueberry' }, 
  { 'id': 4040, 'name': 'banana' },
  {'id' : 5050, name: 'jackfruit'}
]

console.log(except(arr1, arr2))
```